# Way to set all queries to run through SSEM to READ UNCOMMITTED?

Tags: sql-server

We have a hosted application where clients do not get SQL Access.  We have a new client that needs access to SSMS to write queries for reports.  We are installing SSMS on a utility box for the client to log into and use.  The clients accounts will be in the data_reader group.  I want to force all queries to run READ UNCOMMITTED
So not to cause blocking of the application with badly written queries

Comment: What is SSEM? Are you talking about Enterprise Manager? Are you running SQL Server 2000?

Comment: SSEM should have been SSMS sorry have a hard time in my head change gears some times. I fixed my Post TY

Answer (score 1):

If by SSEM you mean SQL Server Management Studio (**SSMS**), there is an option you can set when logged in as this user to run as `READ UNCOMMITTED` by default:

> [image]

But they could easily override that by unchecking the box, setting their own isolation level manually, or calling stored procedures that override. Features like Resource Governor can control a lot of things, but I don't think there's a way to hard-code isolation level for all queries a user submits...

Though, this post might be useful:

- [Can I force a user to use WITH NOLOCK?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47357/can-i-force-a-user-to-use-with-nolock)