# Isolation level with SQL Server and Azure Sql Database Read-Only replica

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, azure-sql-database, isolation-level

I read [here](https://www.apress.com/gp/blog/all-blog-posts/readable-secondaries-in-sql-server/16064064#:%7E:text=When%20you%20run%20the%20queries%20against%20secondary%20nodes%2C%20SQL%20Server%20always%20uses%20the%20snapshot%20isolation%20level%2C%20ignoring%20the%20SET%20TRANSACTION%20ISOLATION%20LEVEL%20statement%20and%20any%20locking%20hints.) and [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/135534/force-everyone-to-use-snapshot-isolation#:%7E:text=All%20queries%20that%20run%20against%20the%20secondary%20databases%20are%20automatically%20mapped%20to%20snapshot%20isolation%20transaction%20level%2C%20even%20when%20other%20transaction%20isolation%20levels%20are%20explicitly%20set.%20Also%2C%20all%20locking%20hints%20are%20ignored.%20This%20eliminates%20reader/writer%20contention) that, when connecting to a Sql Server read-only replica, the isolation level used is ALWAYS `SNAPSHOT`. It says it ignores `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL` statement and any locking hints.

Is this true?

Is it also true for Azure SQL Database replicas?

What happens if the snapshot isolation level is disabled?

Comment: Try disabling it and edit your observation into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when connecting to a Sql Server read-only replica, the isolation level used is ALWAYS SNAPSHOT. It says it ignores SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL statement and any locking hints. Is this true?

Microsoft documentation says the same, see Benefits section of link below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/active-secondaries-readable-secondary-replicas-always-on-availability-groups?view=sql-server-ver15

> Is it also true for Azure Sql Database replicas ?

On both SQL Server and Azure SQL Database, when you connect to readable secondary, transaction isolation level will be  Snapshot

> What happens if the snapshot isolation level is disabled?

Even if you disable `ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION` or `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` on database on primary replica, sessions on secondary will still use Snapshot mode because row versioning will still be used internally

Comment: You contradict yourself by first saying that I can trust it should be using SNAPSHOT isolation and then saying it is actually using RCSI. SNAPSHOT and RCSI are different isolation levels.

Comment: @Clement you are right; found MS doc where it is confirmed - edited the answer. Please remove the downvote